# CKeditor v4 with RTL and LTR on the same page

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have multiple instances of CKeditor 4 on a page. One with an English translation, one with French and one with Arabic. I have tried tweaking to config file upon each firing of the editor instance. However, it always displays the last configuration used and applies to all the textareas. I have been using:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
```

What I really need to do is use something that manipulates just that instance rather than the global config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom config file for each instance of CKEditor you have in the page.
Then reference the custom config file like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config_ltr.js'
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
        customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config_rtl.js'
    });
```

Then you can define your language direction in the different config files.

You can find more here: [CKEditor support](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration)

Comment: This works a treat, thanks very much ;-). I've maybe been staring at this a little too long!